# Wordpress - background image not working with home_url()

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a number of background images I'm using on a WordPress site which is ready to move to production. I'm changing all the localhost absolute links in my `style.css` file. I've changed my code for a background image from this:

```
background: url('http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/homepagemain.jpg') center center no-repeat;
```

To this:

```
 background: url('<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/homepagemain.jpg') center center no-repeat;
```

When I do this the image doesn't show up, not sure if I'm just using the wrong function but this works on my `img` links in my html. How can I fix this? Do I need to use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` to move the image edit into the admin area and away from the stylesheets? Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Is this code in your css file ? It looks like css code with php code in the middle

Comment: Yes it is. Is it the wrong path?

Comment: The php cannot be executed there

Comment: Oh, of course. Do I need to use the thumbnail function to make the URL relative then? At present in the css file it's using local host.

Comment: I would suggest the following: Create a folder in the theme directory and name it "images" and move all your image files there. Then change your code to:
`background:  url('images/FullNameOfFile')center center no-repeat;`

Comment: Just remove http://localhost:8888 and job done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the other answers are making such a simple problem, so complex.

All you need to do is remove `http://localhost:8888` from the image path, thus creating a relative link and it will work fine.

You also get the added benefit of it working on http and https protocols if you decide to change in future. All you need is:

```
background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/homepagemain.jpg') center center no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thanks. What if i want to put my background images in the theme directory so a client can change the image without having to go into the style.css file? Do I create that in my Media directory?

Comment: Just update your URL to point to that theme directory, something like `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/media/image.png`

Comment: Yeah, but that would still need to be changed in the style folder rather than editable in the admin dashboard.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean, what is a style folder? You also didn't mention admin dashboards in your question, just that you had images that aren't working. That sounds like a separate question entirely...

Comment: Sorry - gone off on a tangent. I meant style.css, I'll put another question up on here if I can't solve it but basically I want a client to be able to edit a background image in their admin area rather than have to fiddle through the code.

Comment: Right ok, yes that is a completely different problem entirely and for that you will need to use the PHP functions you mentioned in your question but you will need to create them as inline styles on the elements. Alternatively you can compile your own CSS stylesheets whenever someone saves in the admin, but that is a much bigger task...

Answer (score 1):

use below code in template. because php code does not works in css file. so you must use in php file

```
<?php
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_path = $uploads['baseurl']; // now how to get just the directory name?
?>

<div style="background: url('<?php echo esc_url($upload_path); ?>/2017/07/homepagemain.jpg') center center no-repeat;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your image in the images folder and use the below code in the template:

```
<div style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/homepagemain.jpg') center center no-repeat;"></div>
```

Comment: All my images are in the media folder - how do I create an images folder?

Comment: Create images folder in your theme directory and place your image there